# How can i set a javascript on click trigger on a html response (coming from ajax call )

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im trying to set a trigger on an html response coming from an ajax call 
to show it in a dialog .

ex :  on click on tooth, im triggering the below function , which is will return an html response  ( below )

```
$('.tooth').click(function() { 
    var userid = 1; 
    //alert(id);exit;
    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxCall.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 
            userid: userid
        },
        success: function(response) { 
            $('.modal-body').html(response); 
            $('#empModal').modal('show');  
        }
    });
```

how can i set a jquery trigger on this button ?, in which class should i implement my script ?

html response :

```
$response .= " <button id='toothEndo' class='toothEndo'   name='toothEndo'> ENDO </button> "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your intent is.  I assume you want to add an event listener to the button, not trigger an event.

You need to target that button via normal jQuery logic **AFTER** the API call completes and replaces the html in `$('.modal-body')`.

You can do this by either adding `$('.toothEndo').click(..)` after the `.html()` call in the ajax success callback.

You could also wrap that event into a function, then call that function at that point.

Comment: thanks Man :) , it worked now  however i've tried to do that yesterday and failed ,

Comment: Np. Another, more robust solution would be to target all `.toothEndo` element in the body class with `$('body').on('click', '.toothEndo', function() { ..code.. });`. This will allow you to passively add that event listener to *any* new element loaded via the AJAX call without having to explicitly set the event in the `success` callback.